# Is there a way to override attributes from AssemblyInfo.cs (e.g. AssemblyVersionAttribute)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I'm using dotnet core. This is for a CI process, not local builds. I'd like to allow devs to create AssemblyInfo.cs files for things like title etc but I'd like my build process to have control over the assembly's version.

Currently I'm using the "dotnet build ... /p:Version=1.2.3.4" command, but as soon as an AssemblyInfo.cs file is present this version number is superseded, even if the AssemblyInfo.cs doesn't specify any version properties.

The only way I can control the version from the CLI is to remove the AssemblyInfo.cs file. Is there any way of doing this without resorting to manually altering the AssemblyInfo.cs file before build?

Comment: What tool are you using for CI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tooling generates a custom `.cs` file containing assembly attributes. The compiler only allows each attribute to be defined just one. Usually you'd turn off the automatic assembly info generation completely, but the SDK enables you to control the generation of each attribute individually.

So if you edit the csproj file to contain these property group (inside the `<Project>` element):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- true is the default here -->
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
</PropertyGroup>
```

These properties won't be auto-generated during compilation and you can define them in a custom property. The complete list is [available in the dotnet/sdk repo](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets#L26-L37).

Comment: thanks @martin. We've gone down the route of replacing AssemblyInfo.cs and using these msbuild properties. Even if you specify an AssemblyVersion in the above way, you can still override it from the msbuild command line (which you couldn't when an AssemblyInfo.cs was present)

Comment: Yes that is probably the better way. and you could even set the values in a `Directory.Build.props` file at the solution level for all projects so you don't have to update all projects.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build#directorybuildprops-example

Comment: Full list of `Generate...` properties: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets